# Reading numbers from each line from text file and counting how many times the numbers are repeating

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

I have a file called Numberfiles.txt which contains the following information;

```
[3] 7 17 19
[5] 23 47 0 19 12
[3] 0 17 9
[7] 1 7 24 13 12 0 1
[2] 17 17
```

The first number of each line indicates the number of numbers in a line. 
For example, The first line , [3] 7 17 19,  has 3 numbers which are 7,17 and 19.
I need to count the number of times each number is repeating in the file.
I need to ignore the first number of each line.
The output should be as such:

```
0-3
1-2
2-0
3-0
4-0
5-0
.
.
99-...
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   ifstream f("numbers.txt");
    if (!f) {
        cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "File opened successfully!" << endl;
    }
    int array[100] = { 0 };
    while (!f.eof()) {
        for (int i = 0; i<f.eof();i++){}
        f >> array[i];

    }
    f.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Im stuck on how to add the numbers to the array and how to count the number of times a number is repeating.
I am quite new to programming.

Comment: Is the range of the numbers (from 0 to 99 e.g.) limited?

Comment: FYI, the way this would / should be solved is to use a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, not an array.  If you had the number 1000000 and it was repeated 5 times, how would your array work with that type of input?

Comment: Taking a look at the example output, it seems number are restricted to [0, 99]

Comment: *I need to ignore the first number of each line* -- Aren't you supposed to read the number in-between the brackets?  If so, you're not really ignoring the number.

Comment: Please see my answer below. I am indeed ignoring the first number. I do not need to read it. I just read whatever numbers are available after the brackets. The whole task is not very complicated to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Split code into small functions, it is easier to read and write such code.

```cpp
std::istream& readVec(std::istream& input, std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    char openBracket, closeBracket;
    size_t count;

    if (input >> openBracket >> count >> closeBracket)
    {
        if (openBracket != '[') std::cerr << "error to handle\n";
        if (closeBracket != ']') std::cerr << "error to handle\n";

        vec.reserve(count);
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>{input}, count, std::back_inserter(vec));
    }

    return input;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/7V7BIKDiouD8gfgN

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to read a special format of csv data. Separated by blanks, and skipping the first column. This is a standard task and I will give you detailed explanations. In the end all the reading of the file will be done in a one-liner.

Counting is then a very simple task and will be implemented with a `std::map`.

I will use "modern" C++ elements.

In modern C++ you have algorithms that iterate over ranges. You will often see something like "someAlgoritm(container.begin(), container.end(), someLambda)". The idea is that we iterate over some similar elements.

In your case we iterate over tokens in your input string, and create substrings. This is called tokenizing.

And for exactly that purpose, we have the `std::sregex_token_iterator`. And because we have something that has been defined for such purpose, we should use it.

This thing is an iterator. For iterating over a string, hence sregex. The begin part defines, on what range of input we shall operate, then there is a `std::regex` for what should be matched / or what should not be matched in the input string. The type of matching strategy is given with last parameter.

- 1 --> give me the stuff that I defined in the regex and
- -1 --> give me that what is NOT matched based on the regex.

So, now that we understand the iterator, we can std::copy the tokens from the iterator to our target, a `std::vector` of `std::string`. And since we do not know, how may columns we have, we will use the `std::back_inserter` as a target. This will add all tokens that we get from the `std::sregex_token_iterator` and append it ot our `std::vector<std::string>>`. It does'nt matter how many columns we have.

Good. Such a statement could look like

```
std::copy(                          // We want to copy something
    std::sregex_token_iterator      // The iterator begin, the sregex_token_iterator. Give back first token
    (
        line.begin(),               // Evaluate the input string from the beginning
        line.end(),                 // to the end
        re,                         // Add match a comma
        -1                          // But give me back not the comma but everything else 
    ),
    std::sregex_token_iterator(),   // iterator end for sregex_token_iterator, last token + 1
    std::back_inserter(cp.columns)  // Append everything to the target container
);
```

For your special example, we will skip the first column with `std::next`. That will simply increase the iterator by one.

Now we can understand, how this copy operation works.

Next step. We want to read from a file. The file conatins also some kind of same data. The same data are rows.

And as for above, we can iterate of similar data. If it is the file input or whatever. For this purpose C++ has the `std::istream_iterator`. This is a template and as a template parameter it gets the type of data that it should read and, as a constructor parameter it gets a reference to an input stream. It doesnt't matter, if the input stream is a `std::cin`, or a `std::ifstream` or a `std::istringstream`. The behaviour is identical for all kinds of streams.

And since we do not have files an SO, I use (in the below example) a `std::istringstream` to store the input csv file. But of course you can open a file, by defining a `std::ifstream testCsv(filename)`. No problem.

And with `std::istream_iterator`, we iterate over the input and read similar data. In our case one problem is that we want to iterate over special data and not over some build in data type.

To solve this, we define a Proxy class, which does the internal work for us (we do not want to know how, that should be encapsulated in the proxy). In the proxy we overwrite the type cast operator, to get the result to our expected type for the `std::istream_iterator`.

And the last important step. A `std::vector` has a range constructor. It has also a lot of other constructors that we can use in the definition of a variable of type `std::vector`. But for our purposes this constructor fits best.

So we define a variable csv and use its range constructor and give it a begin of a range and an end of a range. And, in our specific example, we use the begin and end iterator of `std::istream_iterator`.

If we combine all the above, reading the complete CSV file is a *one-liner*, it is the definition of a variable with calling its range constructor.

Counting is ultra simple. We use a `std::map`. The [] operator will add elements, if they are not yet existing. If they are existing, the ++ wil increment the count.

Please see the resulting code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>

std::istringstream testCsv{ R"([3] 7 17 19
[5] 23 47 0 19 12
[3] 0 17 9
[7] 1 7 24 13 12 0 1
[2] 17 17)" };


// Define Alias for easier Reading
using Columns = std::vector<std::string>;
using CSV = std::vector<Columns>;


// Proxy for the input Iterator
struct ColumnProxy {    
    // Overload extractor. Read a complete line
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, ColumnProxy& cp) {

        // Read a line
        std::string line; cp.columns.clear();
        std::getline(is, line);

        // The delimiter
        const std::regex re(" ");

        // Split values and copy into resulting vector
        std::copy(std::next(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1)),
            std::sregex_token_iterator(),
            std::back_inserter(cp.columns));
        return is;
    }

    // Type cast operator overload.  Cast the type 'Columns' to std::vector<std::string>
    operator std::vector<std::string>() const { return columns; }
protected:
    // Temporary to hold the read vector
    Columns columns{};
};


int main()
{
    // Define variable CSV with its range constructor. Read complete CSV in this statement, So, one liner
    CSV csv{ std::istream_iterator<ColumnProxy>(testCsv), std::istream_iterator<ColumnProxy>() };

    //Definition of counter
    std::map<std::string, size_t> counter{};
    // Count
    std::for_each(csv.begin(), csv.end(), [&counter](Columns& c) {
        std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), [&counter](std::string& s){counter[s]++; }); });

    // Output
    for (size_t i = 0U; i<100U; ++i)
        std::cout << i << "-" << counter[std::to_string(i)] << "\n";
    return 0;        
}
```

The result is a ultra simple piece of code with a high flexibility.

In function main, you will see just some statements.

I hope it helps . . .